# Multiple-tags input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I recently started with AngularJS, and am currently working on a simple form with a tags input field and a submit button. The input field is supposed to accept multiple tags so that on clicking submit all the tags get saved as an array.

Now I am currently using ngTagsInput directive which I found on github(http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/). This directive gives me `<tags-input></tags-input>` HTML element which creates an input field that accepts multiple tags before submission. Here is what it look like(look at the **Tags** field):

[image]

This works fine, what I need now is a directive which gives me similar functionality but instead of an element ie. `<tags-input>`, I want an attribute which I can include inside the conventional `<input>` element like  `<input attribute='tags-input'>` .

**Question:**

1. Is there a way I can use ngTagsInput as an attribute?
2. Are there any other directives out there which may suit my need? If yes then please post the link in the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need it? Maybe the problem is not here...

Comment: @k102 Actually I am trying to create the form through Angular and Symfony2 so I need a standard HTML element like `<input>` or maybe something else but it has to be a standard element.

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 There will be an input element within the elements it creates. You can't have this behavior with only an input an element, you need a wrapping element where the tags get displayed. text field only displays regular text in it.

Comment: I've made a great, super customization, lightweight one - [github.com/yairEO/tagify](http://github.com/yairEO/tagify)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As you can see on `tags-input.js` file, the directive is configured as an `element`:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        tags: '=ngModel',
        text: '=?',
        templateScope: '=?',
        tagClass: '&',
        onTagAdding: '&',
        onTagAdded: '&',
        onInvalidTag: '&',
        onTagRemoving: '&',
        onTagRemoved: '&',
        onTagClicked: '&',
    },
```

But you can write your own directive with `attribute` type and "replace" your `div element` to the `tags-input element`.

I wrote this example:

```
app.directive('tagsInputAttr', 
  function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope:{
        ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var attrsText = '';
        $.each($(element)[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
          if (attr.nodeName === "tags-input-attr" || attr.nodeName === "ng-model") 
            return;

          attrsText += " " + attr.nodeName + "='" + attr.nodeValue + "'";
        });

        var html ='<tags-input ng-model="ngModel" ' + attrsText + '></tags-input>';
        e =$compile(html)($scope);
        $(element).replaceWith(e);
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Now you can configure your tags-input elements in two ways:

Element way:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="text" placeholder="Add a Tag here..." ></tags-input>
```

Attribute way:

```
<input tags-input-attr ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="text" placeholder="Add a Tag here..."  />
```

You can see this in action at Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yjkX22

Comment: Thanks for the answer. M new to AngularJS so I don't know how to make changes in the ngTagsInput directive, so that it accepts tags-input as an attribute or even better, a class name. No clue what to look for.

Comment: Also, is it recommended to change the directive definition here?

Comment: Notice I didn't modified the original directive. As you can see in code (see at Plunker) I created a new directive.

Comment: And no, it's not recommended change the original directive. I just created a new directive (`tags-input-attr`) that creates an element who will fire the original directive (`tags-input`).

Comment: I think I get it. Lemme try ur solution

Comment: Ur solution works with `<div>` but not with `<input>`, I need it inside `<input>` element. Any suggestions? Also in your solution, can I use the attributes like `add-on-paste="true" display-property="tagname" placeholder="Add a Tag" add-from-autocomplete-only="true"` that I used inside `<tags-input>` similarly or do I need to make changes to ur Directive?

Comment: It was a great challenge. I made some modifications and now I think you will like the result. My answer for your last question is Yes. You (right now) can put your own attributes in your `input` field and the directive will automaticly transport then all to the `tags-input` element.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this. This will work like a charm :)

Comment: Hey, m stuck at another issue on same directive. I know this is too much to ask, but m a noob and m desperate right now xD, so just in case if u can spare some time here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371035/angularjs-custom-directive-to-wrap-ngtagsinputs-autocomplete

Comment: It was a great challenge again. I made some changes and answered your new question. Hope it can help you.