# Customizing ngTagsInput & autoComplete directives (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tags

I am new to AngularJS and am currently working on an input field, which can accept multiple tags at a time along with the auto-complete feature, which display the available tags as dropdown options. For this I am using the `ngTagsInput` directive I found on the web(http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/), which gives me a custom HTML element `<tags-input>`. This works beautifully:

`index.html`:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];

  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.json');
  };
});
</script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
    <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="text" placeholder="Add a Tag" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
           <auto-complete max-results-to-show="4" min-length="2" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
</div>
```

`tags.json`:

```
[
  { "text": "Tag1" },
  { "text": "Tag2" },
  { "text": "Tag3" },
  { "text": "Tag4" },
  { "text": "Tag5" },
  { "text": "Tag6" },
  { "text": "Tag7" },
  { "text": "Tag8" },
  { "text": "Tag9" },
  { "text": "Tag10" }
]
```

However I wanted to use the standard HTML `<input>` element instead of the custom `<tags-input>` element which comes along with the directive, so with a lot of help and using `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` I was able to do it here:

Here is the new `index.html`:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { "id":1, "tagname": 'Tag1' },
    { "id":2, "tagname": 'Tag2' },
    { "id":3, "tagname": 'Tag3' },
    { "id":4, "tagname": 'Tag4' }
  ];

    $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.json');
  };

});

app.directive('tagsInputAttr', 
  function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope:{
        ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var attrsText = '';
        $.each($(element)[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
          if (attr.nodeName === "tags-input-attr" || attr.nodeName === "ng-model") 
            return;

          attrsText += " " + attr.nodeName + "='" + attr.nodeValue + "'";
        });

        var html ='<tags-input ng-model="ngModel" ' + attrsText + '></tags-input>';
        e =$compile(html)($scope);
        $(element).replaceWith(e);
      }
    };
  }
);
</script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <input tags-input-attr ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="tagname" placeholder="Add tags here..." add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
      <auto-complete max-results-to-show="3" min-length="2" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </input>

  </div>
```

And the new `tags.json`:

```
[
  { "id":1, "tagname": "Tag1" },
  { "id":2, "tagname": "Tag2" },
  { "id":3, "tagname": "Tag3" },
  { "id":4, "tagname": "Tag4" },
  { "id":5, "tagname": "Tag5" },
  { "id":6, "tagname": "Tag6" },
  { "id":7, "tagname": "Tag7" },
  { "id":8, "tagname": "Tag8" },
  { "id":9, "tagname": "Tag9" },
  { "id":10, "tagname": "Tag10" }
]
```

As you can notice,the new directive `tagsInputAttr`, which wraps the `<tags-input>` provides the same functionality and can be used inside `<input>` tag as an attribute along with the rest of attributes such as `ng-model`, `display-property` etc. So I don't have to use the `<tags-input>` element directly. The **problem** is that the `<auto-complete>` placed inside the `<input>` tag doesn't work.

For this I need to alter my directive, considering the following:

**Note:** I do not want to use jquery for this

My question is how do I wrap the `<auto-complete>` inside the same `<input tags-input-attr>` element:

1. Either as an attribute inside the same `<input tags-input-attr>` element
2. or as an attribute inside a standard HTML element like `<div>` or `<span>`, wrapped inside the same `<input tags-input-attr>` element.
3. If not the above two, then as last resort, as the `<auto-complete>` tag wrapped inside the same `<input tags-input-attr>` element

All help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes on the previus directive and now it accepts all kind of transformation from `attribute` to `element` directive.

You still have the `elem-as-attr` attribute, but now you have to specify the `value` of it, that it will be the `element` that will replace.

*Example:*

```
<div elem-as-attr="tags-input"></div>
```

## Your application JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.allTags = [
    { "id":1, "tagname": "Tag1" },
    { "id":2, "tagname": "Tag2" },
    { "id":3, "tagname": "Tag3" },
    { "id":4, "tagname": "Tag4" },
    { "id":5, "tagname": "Tag5" },
    { "id":6, "tagname": "Tag6" },
    { "id":7, "tagname": "Tag7" },
    { "id":8, "tagname": "Tag8" },
    { "id":9, "tagname": "Tag9" },
    { "id":10, "tagname": "Tag10" }
  ];

  $scope.myTags =[
    $scope.allTags[2],
    $scope.allTags[4],
    $scope.allTags[8]
  ];

  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $scope.allTags;
  };
});
```

## The directive code:

```
app.directive('elemAsAttr', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      return function($scope) {
        var attrs = tElement[0].attributes;

        var attrsText = '';
        for (var i=0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
          var attr = attrs.item(i);
          if (attr.nodeName === "elem-as-attr") {
            continue;
          }
          attrsText += " " + attr.nodeName + "='" + attr.nodeValue + "'";        
        }

        var hasModel = $(tElement)[0].hasAttribute("ng-model");
        var innerHtml = $(tElement)[0].innerHTML;
        var html = '<' + tAttrs.elemAsAttr  + attrsText + '>' + innerHtml + '</' + tAttrs.elemAsAttr + '>';

        var e = hasModel ? $compile(html)($scope) : html;
        $(tElement).replaceWith(e);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

## HTML code:

#### Element way:

```
  <tags-input ng-model="myTags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="tagname" placeholder="Add a Tag" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
    <auto-complete max-results-to-show="10" display-property="tagname" min-length="2" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
  </tags-input>
```

#### Attribute way:

```
  <div elem-as-attr="tags-input" ng-model="myTags" add-on-paste="true" display-property="tagname" placeholder="Add tags here..." add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
    <div elem-as-attr="auto-complete" max-results-to-show="10" display-property="tagname" min-length="2" source="loadTags($query)"></div>
  </div>
```

## Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9TqsXy

> Note that you cannot use the `input` element for the `tagsInput`
>   because the `input` element does not have the closing tag in HTML. So
>   you will not be able to put the `auto-complete` element inside it.