# ngTagsInput with autocomplete in a form and add to db

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I've been trying to use ngTagsInput with its Autocomplete feature (mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos) in a html form to submit recipes in Mongodb.

Basically, I'm using ngTagsInput with Autocomplete to query my ingredients db and display ingredients tags in the 'Ingredients in the recipe'.

*It works fine*, up until I save the recipe, and the ingredients are not saved.

I know where the problem is but I haven't found a solution yet. 
Here is the 'ingredients' field of my add recipe page without ngTagsInput, just a normal text field:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="ingredients">List of ingredients</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ingredients" ng-model="form.ingredients">
        </div>
```

And here is the 'ingredients' field using ngTagsInput (Working fine, but not saving):

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="recipeApiController">    
        <tags-input for="Ingredients" id="Ingredients" ng-model="tags" display-property="ingredientID" placeholder="Commence à taper le nom d'un ingrédient..." add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
        <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
        </tags-input>
        </div>
```

Because I'm replacing ng-model="form.ingredients" with ng-model="tags" required to use ngTagsInput, those ingredient tags are not saved when clicking my "Add recipe" button.

Here is the "save to db" part of my recipeApiController, used on the "add recipe" form page:

```
$scope.addToDatabase = function(){
    RecipeApi.Recipe.save({}, $scope.form, 
    function(data){
        $scope.recipe.push(data);
    },
    function(err){
        bootbox.alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

Do you have any idea how I could fix that, and save those tags?

Thanks in advance guys. I didn't want this post to be too long but if you need more info, code, I'll be super reactive to provide it. This would help me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383917/6858949**

Basically, I couldn't get those tags to save because ng-model didn't work inside the `<tags-input>` tags. I therefore used this guy's directive to change the `<tags-input>` to an attribute:

```
<div elem-as-attr="tags-input"></div>
```

**Here's the directive code**:

```
app.directive('elemAsAttr', function($compile) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
require: '?ngModel',
replace: true,
scope: true,
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
  return function($scope) {
    var attrs = tElement[0].attributes;

    var attrsText = '';
    for (var i=0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
      var attr = attrs.item(i);
      if (attr.nodeName === "elem-as-attr") {
        continue;
      }
      attrsText += " " + attr.nodeName + "='" + attr.nodeValue + "'";        
    }

    var hasModel = $(tElement)[0].hasAttribute("ng-model");
    var innerHtml = $(tElement)[0].innerHTML;
    var html = '<' + tAttrs.elemAsAttr  + attrsText + '>' + innerHtml + '</' + tAttrs.elemAsAttr + '>';

    var e = hasModel ? $compile(html)($scope) : html;
    $(tElement).replaceWith(e);
  };
}
}
});
```

I don't think this is optimal, but with my current knowledge of code, I'm thankful I found this solution. ✌

**EDIT:**
I am now using ui-select: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
And definitely recommend it

**EDIT:**
I put the code in the code box